# How long must I wait for security questions to reset

Tags: ios-appstore

I made an appleid around 4 years ago, and just started to use it recently. For security, I had 3 security questions, but I forgot the answers so I reset them. However, when I try to make a purchase, it still asks me  the same security questions that I don't know the answers to. Does anyone know how long I have to wait for them to reset?

Comment: The last time I saw something about a waiting period, it was either 6 or 8 hours, but I can't say for certain.  Usually, it should be on the "reset" page how long the lockout is for.  The best thing to do is to [contact Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204169)